# DRF create only works if serializer is set to (many=True)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue with a POST request view.

DRF will throw an attribute error if I do not set the serializer(AnswerSurveySerializer) to (many=True) but I just want to post a single entry for the field which is a foreignkey.

Appreciate any advise and thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Survey(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='surveys',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status


class Answer(models.Model):

    history = HistoricalRecords()
    survey = models.ForeignKey(
        Survey, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(
        Choice, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class AnswerSurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Survey
        fields = ('id',)


class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    survey = AnswerSurveySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Answer
        fields = ('survey',)
```

views.py

```
class AddAnswerView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Handles creating answers to MCQ."""
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
```

Comment: What is **`status`** in your **`Survey`** model?

Comment: Thanks. You just spotted a mistake. It seems to work now. Silly me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your **`__str__`** method of **`Survey`** model. The `__str__` method return (***trying to return***) an attribute `status`, but `Survey` model class doesn't have `status`.
 So remove the **`__str__`** method from the model or change to something meaningful as,

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='surveys',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.is_completed
```